# How do I set a value in JSON response in Groovy script in SOAP UI

Tags: groovy, soapui

I have two REST request which I am trying to run in SOAP UI. I want to feed response from one REST request to the other REST request. I am using property transfer for this. I first want to modify a Value in Response from 1st request and then feed it . I am trying this

```
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper
import groovy.json.JsonOutput
// request
def request = '''{"data":{
  "supplementaryMessages" : [ ],
  "requisitionHeaders" : [ {
    "dataOperation" : "UPDATE"
  } ]
}}'''
// parse the request
def jsonReq = new JsonSlurper().parseText(request);

// get the response where you've the values you want to get
// using the name of your test step
responseContent = testRunner.testCase.getTestStepByName("Fetch1").getPropertyValue("response")
// parse response
def jsonResp = new JsonSlurper().parseText(responseContent)

// get the values from your first test response 
// and set it in the request of the second test
jsonResp.data.requisitionHeaders.dataOperation = jsonReq.data.requisitionHeaders.dataOperation
```

When I run this I am getting the Type Mismatch error .It could be very simple issue but I am new to Groovy .

Comment: Can you show the response sample of your first request?

Comment: And which data you want to retrieve so that you can use it in the next request? And by the way, if you are using groovy script step, property transfer step would become redundant.